# Add timesatmp to a SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like PHP to tell me when a maximum/minimum temperature was recorded.

This produces the max temp OK:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT MAX(Temp) AS max_temp FROM readings");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
echo "Max temp ". $row["max_temp"]."<br>";
```

The date and time of the measurements as stored as a timestamp, in a row labelled '*Added*'.

I've tried countless ideas, like this below, but am getting nowhere:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT MAX(Temp) AS max_temp FROM readings BETWEEN '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-30'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
$date = strtotime($row['Added']);
echo $date;
echo "Time: ".date('d/m/y', $date)."<br>";
echo "Max temp between dates ". $row["max_temp"].$date."<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the column name of where the timestamps are stored, as well as specifying the `WHERE` clause.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT MAX(Temp) AS max_temp FROM readings WHERE Added BETWEEN '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-30'");
```

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT MAX(Temp) AS max_temp FROM readings WHERE Added BETWEEN '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-30'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$date = strtotime($row['Added']);
// echo $date;
echo "Time: ".date('d/m/y', $date)."<br>";
echo "Max temp between dates ". $row["max_temp"].$date."<br>";}`  Gives this result:     Notice: Undefined index: Added in X:\Sites\ral\index.php on line 23
Time: 01/01/70
Max temp between dates 19.4  (Line 23 is the "$date = strtotime" line.)

Comment: You're only passing `Added` to the WHERE clause. If you want to get the value back out, then you need to add it to the SELECT clause. `SELECT Added, MAX(Temp) FROM...`

Comment: It's getting there, thank you.   ` $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT Added, MAX(Temp) AS max_temp FROM readings WHERE Added BETWEEN '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-30'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$date = strtotime($row['Added']);
// echo $date;
echo "Date: ".date('d/m/y', $date)."<br>";
echo "Max temp between dates ". $row["max_temp"]. " ". $date."<br>";}`   Now gives me   Date: 01/11/19
Max temp between dates 19.4 1572562802  Why is the $date still in Unix format, even after the strtodate?

Comment: Fixed it with 'echo `Max temp between dates ". $row["max_temp"]. " ". date('d/m/y', $date).`

Comment: Because you assign the unix date to `$date`, but echo `Date: ".date('d/m/y', $date)`, but you never reassign the formatted date.